# Function $T(r, \theta) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$ NOT injective at $\mathbb{R}^3$ domain

Tags: calculus

I let you know I am concerned about the definition of an injective function:

A function is injective at a region $ D^*$ if $(u, v) \in D$ and $(u', v') \in D*, T(u, v)=T(u', v') \Rightarrow u=u'$ and $v=v'$

**My aim is understanding why the function  $T(r, \theta) = (r\cos \theta, r\sin \theta)$ is not injective if its domain is all $\mathbb{R}^3$**

Let's pick the region $D^* = [0,1]\times[0,2\pi]$. I worked with the points $A(0,0), B(0,2\pi), C(1,0), D(1, 2\pi).$ $A(0,0) B(0,2\pi)$ result in the same point $P(0,0)$ at $D$. Therefore, we can assure that $T : D^* \to D$ is not one-to-one. Is that enough?

I made some research and this is what I found out:

Then if $r=0$  and $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$ and  $L$ is regarded as one of the rectangle's side, $T$ will convert $L$ into a single point (unity disk's center)

However, if we have the region $S^* = (0,1]\times[0,2\pi)$ Then $T$ is injective

To sum up, I would say this could prove it is not injective at $\mathbb{R}^2$, not at $\mathbb{R}^3$. What am I missing?

Sources: Vector calculus, Jerrold E. Marsden and Anthony J. Tromba

Comment: $T(0,\theta)=(0,0)$ for all $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$T(r,\theta)=T(r,\theta + 2k\pi )$$ T is not injective  on $\mathbb {R}^2.$

There is no need to involve    $\mathbb {R}^3$ in this problem.

Comment: Sir but it depends on the region's domain, don't you think? I mean, at region S it is injective

Comment: Of course it is injective if you restrict your domain. No question about it.